# Help identify this component (probably some sort of thermal fuse)

Tags: identification

This is a part taken from an old steam cooker. It has two terminals at the top. The first terminal is connected to the phase wire (230 V AC) as it enters the device and from the second terminal it is routed further into the device. For this reason I think it is probably some sort of a fuse.

[image: first image]

The two terminals on top are bridged by a two thin metal sheets. There is a vertical ceramic rod that goes through the part, pushing on those metals from downwards. When the rod is pushed up, the metal sheets are disconnected. In the base there is what I guess may be some bimetallic sheet that would push the rod up when the device overheats.

I would like to know if it is indeed a fuse and how is this component called exactly. I tried to find some pictures of fuses but they looked very different from what I have.

As a new member on this site I cannot post that many (that is 4) pictures, so I have to give a [link to a HTML page where additional photos are](http://is.muni.cz/www/374368/38786227/40823195/?furl=/www/374368/38786227/40823195/;lang=en;so=pd;gal=).

Comment: It's a thermal switch. Fuses are objects that have to be replaced once they blow.

Comment: A thermal switch is also called a "thermostat". Sometimes they're adjustable, and sometimes (like this one) they're fixed.

Comment: Repairs to consumer products are off-topic.

Comment: @LeonHeller He didn't ask for repair advice, he is asking for a component identification.

Answer (score 1):

It is a thermostat as [Dave Tweed](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/11683/dave-tweed) and [Kaz](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/9414/kaz) noticed.

I got a similar one and it has the temerature written on it:

[image]